# No method matching your arguments, available [] python pyjnius

Tags: python, kivy, pyjnius

I want to create app. In this app user can upload file from gallery like in 'WhatsApp'. I have the code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from jnius import autoclass
import os

class TestingApp(App):
    def build(self):
        fl = FloatLayout()
        try:
            Intent = autoclass('android.content.Intent')
            activity = autoclass('android.app.Activity')
            intent = Intent()
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT)
            intent.setType("image/*")
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
            activity.startActivity(intent)
        except Exception as error:
            fl.add_widget(Label(text=(str(error)), font_size=(19)))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestingApp().run()
```

but when I start app, I get the error:

```
No methods matching your arguments, available []
```

How can I fix it. I hope you help me...

Comment: Can you post the full traceback?

Comment: @inclement it is full traceback